# Geometry Nodes: How to make a vertex color gradient on a tree depending on distance to root point?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

I'm trying to create a vertex color gradient on a mesh created by converting a branch made with hand drawn curves to a mesh using geometry nodes.

I want to color each edge ring on the created mesh depending on the distance to the origin point of the branch, but crawling along each parent branch. So not only the distance from the point to the branch origin, but also including all the point along the branch before it.

I also need to color the leaves which are instanced on the branch a solid color, of the closest edge ring to the origin point of the instanced leaf.

*How the branch is looking:*

[image: Branch:]

*The branch contains separated splines:*

[image: Separated splines:]

*The result I'm trying to accomplish, made using a MEL script in Maya:*

[image: The result I'm trying to accomplish, made using a MEL script in Maya:]

Is this possible to achieve using geometry nodes, and how would one go about doing that?

Comment: What algorithm did you settle on in your MEL script for jumping the gaps? You want the total length along the branches to the root?

Comment: @RobinBetts The branch is constructed with separated geometry using predictable cylindrical topology in Maya. The objects are parented into a hierarchy with the main stem as the first object. The script loops over every edge loop on each piece, backwards along the hierarchy. 

I jump the gaps by finding the center point of the closest edge loop to each object's pivot point.

So what I'm trying to do is get the length of every point on the spline, crawling backwards along the branch to the origin of the branch.

Comment: 'Centre point of closest loop'  (hopefully, parent)' If a similar method is acceptable in Blender, I think that should be possible in GN. If you mean to _construct_  the tree in GN, that would be simpler still .. the construction data would be there without a 'closest' search.

Comment: A good approach with Geometry Nodes would be to convert the Tree Curve to Mesh and merge the points at the base of the branches. Select the end points and run Shortest Path set up for these points with End Point the base of the tree. Convert the resulted shortest paths to curves (splines) and calculate each spline length. Assign distance attributes to each curve points based on spline length and transfer them to the closest points in the original Tree Curve object.